# Tests fail when concatenating nested array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, testing, jestjs, radix-sort

Implemented a [Radix Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) which sorts a list of numbers. Here is my code:

```js
function getDigit(number, index, lengthOfLongestNumber) {
  let numberString = number.toString();

  numberString = numberString.padStart(lengthOfLongestNumber, '0');

  return parseInt(numberString[index], 10) || 0;
}

function getLengthOfLongestNumber(numbers) {
  // return Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.max(...numbers))) + 1;

  let largestNumber = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] > largestNumber) {
      largestNumber = numbers[i];
    }
  }

  return largestNumber.toString().length;
}

function radixSort(numbers) {
  const lengthOfLongestNumber = getLengthOfLongestNumber(numbers);

  for (let i = lengthOfLongestNumber - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    const buckets = new Array(10).fill().map(() => []);

    while (numbers.length) {
      const number = numbers.shift();

      buckets[getDigit(number, i, lengthOfLongestNumber)].push(number);
    }

    for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      // numbers = numbers.concat(buckets[j]);  ---> uncomment this line and comment out the following while loop
      // numbers = [...numbers, ...buckets[j]]; ---> or uncomment this line and comment out the following while loop
      while (buckets[j].length) {
        numbers.push(buckets[j].shift());
      }
    }
  }

  return numbers;
}
```

Tests fail when I merge `buckets` array into `numbers` array using [`concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) in `radixSort` function (inside inner `for` loop). But it somehow passes if I use `while` loop instead.

You can see and run tests in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-dust-q0tx0?file=/src/radix.js:936-1114).

Why is this happening? What is the difference between them that causes tests fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the *returned* array it doesn't matter which of those alternatives you use, but if the tests expect you to sort the *given* array, so that after the call the input array has been sorted *itself*, then indeed, the commented-out alternatives will not work. This is because those alternatives *assign* to `numbers` instead of mutating it.

Just check the difference between the alternatives when ignoring the returned array, but looking at the given array:

```
let arr = [521, 219, 100, 422, 889, 529, 491, 777, 641, 882, 229];
radixSort(arr);
console.log(arr);
```

The commented-out alternatives will log an empty array.

The correct version *mutates* `numbers`, and does not *assign* a (new) array to it.

To avoid the loop, you can do this mutation also like this:

```
numbers.push(...buckets[j]);
```

And you can even replace the `for` loop around that statement, with just this line:

```
numbers.push(...buckets.flat());
```

Comment: Perfect! I understand now that `radixSort` function mutates the *given* array in both cases but commented-out lines make it an empty array by assigning *a new* array. That's why `expect([]).toEqual(nums.sort());` is passing in tests. Thank you!